# Understanding mongo db explain

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I fired a query and tried to explain it on mongo console and got

```
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 8,
"nscannedObjects" : 17272,
"nscanned" : 17272,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 21836,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 21836,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 184,
```

Most of the things are explained in http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain, but I cannot understand what does nscannedObjectsAllPlans, nscannedAllPlans means. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`nscanned` and `nscannedObjects` report results for the winning [query plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/).

`nscannedAllPlans` and `nscannedObjectsAllPlans` report results for all plans.

[Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html#explain.executionStats.totalKeysExamined)

> Number of index entries scanned. `totalKeysExamined` corresponds to the `nscanned` field returned by `cursor.explain()` in earlier versions of MongoDB.

For example:

```js
t = db.jstests_explainb;
t.drop();

t.ensureIndex( { a:1, b:1 } );
t.ensureIndex( { b:1, a:1 } );

t.save( { a:0, b:1 } );
t.save( { a:1, b:0 } );

// Older mongodb (< 3.0? )
t.find( { a:{ $gte:0 }, b:{ $gte:0 } } ).explain( true );
    {
      "isMultiKey": false,
      "n": 2,
      "nscannedObjects": 2,
      "nscanned": 2,
      "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 6,
      "nscannedAllPlans": 6,
      "scanAndOrder": false,
      "indexOnly": false,
      "nYields": 0,
      "nChunkSkips": 0,
      "millis": 2,
    ...
    }

// MongoDB 4.4
t.find( { a:{ $gte:0 }, b:{ $gte:0 } } ).explain( true );
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.jstests_explainb",
        ...
        "queryHash" : "CB67518C",
        "planCacheKey" : "5E76CDD1",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1",
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "b" : 1,
                        "a" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "b_1_a_1",
                }
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 2,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2, // <-- same as `nscanned`
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2, // <--
        "executionStages" : { ... }
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: So should I worry if nscannedObjectsAllPlans, nscannedAllPlans are giving large value while the nscanned is still in the acceptable range?

Comment: I don't think so - I believe it's only when explain() is called that it performs those other plans in the first place.

Comment: Running multiple plans is basically how MongoDB decides which query plan it should use. It executes all the plans it could use in parallel the first time the query is run, then periodically after a number of queries or changes to the data. As soon as one finishes, it caches it as the plan to use, cancels the others, and will use that plan until the next time it decides to refresh it.

Comment: @DavidMason the query optimizer decides which plan to use based on which plan returns 101 documents the fastest. See here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/